# Overhead using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, pthreads, scheduled-tasks

I am using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to delay short tasks executation in x amount of time (no more than a few secconds).
I would like to know what would be the overhead if i schedule arround 7K tasks ever 3 secconds. 
is there a better alternative to do such a thing ( performance wise ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need to do it in multithreaded way, I guess there are no solutions with significantly less overhead.

However, if everything you need is delayed execution, not execution in different threads (for example, for some kind of simulation), then perhaps you can get rid of synchronization overhead by running all tasks consequently in the same thread. For example, you can place your tasks into `PriorityQueue` ordered by execution time, and create a task running loop that whould run the first task from the queue at its execution time.

Answer (score 1):

if I was in your shoes I would look at Quartz: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/, then decide for yourself.